# How to search for "python" the programming language on Google Trends?

Tags: google-search, google-trends

If I type `ruby` on [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) then it suggests "the programming language", which is what I want.

But if I type `python` then it doesn't suggest the programming language.

**Question**

How can I get it to search for python the programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using too many search terms is counterproductive, so limit your search terms to the minimum number of words necessary to convey the desired meaning of the search term. You should also try to be as specific as possible. Here are the results of the search term `python programming` on Google Trends.

[image]